# Android - Returning a position of an item in an ArrayList that appears multiple times

Tags: android, arraylist

I have three ArrayLists, two are Strings and the last one is an Integer.

The first ArrayList contains the specific Variant (variantArray) for a certain Product like the flavor variant of a cola, the second one contains the Unit (unitArray) that contains the unit like the size (80oz, 500mL, 1L) of the product, and the last one is the quantity *(quantityArray).

This is the class I use.

```
public class CurrentOrderClass {

  //ArrayLists
  private ArrayList<String> variantArray = new ArrayList<String>();
  private ArrayList<String> unitArray = new ArrayList<String>();
  private ArrayList<Integer> quantityArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();


  //TODO ArrayList functions
  public ArrayList<String> getUnitArray() {
      return unitArray;
  }

  public void setUnitArray(ArrayList<String> unitArray) {
      this.unitArray = unitArray;
  }

  public void addToUnitArray(String unit){
      this.unitArray.add(unit);
  }



  public ArrayList<Integer> getQuantityArray() {
      return quantityArray;
  }

  public void setQuantityArray(ArrayList<Integer> quantityArray) {
      this.quantityArray = quantityArray;
  }

  public void addToQuantityArray(int quantity){
      this.quantityArray.add(quantity);
  }

  public ArrayList<String> getVariantArray() {
      return variantArray;
  }

  public void setVariantArray(ArrayList<String> variantArray) {
      this.variantArray = variantArray;
  }

  public void addToVariantArray(String variantArray){
      this.variantArray.add(variantArray);
  }


  @Override
      public String toString() {
         return "[ product=" + productName + ", variants=" + 
            variants + " , unit=" + unit + " , quantity=" + quantity + "]";
      }

}
```

I take in user input so the user chooses the Variant, Unit, and Quantity and the input is then stored in their respective ArrayLists.

However, I'm having a problem updating the ArrayLists when the user inputs a Variant and a Unit that already exists in the ArrayLists but only with a different Quantity. What I want to do is not to add the new entry, but update the current ArrayLists in such a way that when the user inputs a variant and a unit but different quantity, I'd only update the quantity.

The first thing I tried was to see if the input already exists in the ArrayList by using `indexOf(userInputVariant)` and then check if it matches with a `indexOf(userInputUnit)`, this would mean that the user input repeated already. However, I don't think indexOf runs on that logic and the value it returns is the value where it found the first instance of the `userInputVariant` string.

The second attempt I tried was using a for each loop, however, I'm once again having a hard time returning the index I want properly.

I instantiate an object of the `CurrentOrderClass` named `currentOrder` and prepopulated the first 10 elements of its variantArray with "Grape"

After that, I tried this if-else statement:

```
if( (currentOrder.getVariantArray().indexOf(product.getVariant()[variantPosition]) ==
     currentOrder.getUnitArray().indexOf(product.getUnit()[position])
```

However, as mentioned above, indexOf returns an int where it first found the String that I told it to find, I don't think it checks if it exists after that certain position.

The second code I tried was to use a for-each and return the position from there, but again, it only returned position = 0.

```
for( String Grape : currentOrder.getVariantArray() ){
      Log.d("Angelo", "Retrived Element: " + Grape 
           + " at position = " + currentOrder.getVariantArray().indexOf(Grape));
}
```

I'm currently thinking of running a for-each loop inside a for-each loop but I don't know how to make it return the proper position that I want.

Does anyone have an idea on how to make it work properly? I need to return the position of an item that appears multiple times in my variantArray by "cross-referencing" it  with my unitArray. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should make a `Product` class and build an `ArrayList` of those instead?

Comment: where is your code for what you have tried?

Comment: @Geobits yes they are in a class.

Comment: @Peshal okay I'll update my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One for loop is enough in this case.

This will some thing like:

```
isExist = false;
for(index = 0; index<variantArray.size(); index++){
    if(variantArray.get(index) == userChoiceVariant &&
        unitArray.get(index) == userChoiceUnit){
        //update quantity
        isExist = true;
    }
}
if(!isExist){
    //insert order
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first solution I reach is: "Search all the indexes matching with the user input in the variant array, store this in another `ArrayList<Integer>`, name it, `matchingVariants` for now. Then, for each of the ints in `matchingVariants` get that position of the units list. If one of this items matches, then you should update, otherwise insert.

However, I think a better solution is wrap Variants and Units in one class, for example `Product` with attributes `String variant` and `String unit`. Implementing `equals` method you can forget about your variants and units lists and have only one `ArrayList<Product>`

As a next step, I would use a `Map` with `Product` as key and `Integer` as values. So I can just update the `Map` rather than having all the lists you have.